# Having a Movie as a transition between two View Controllers - where to put this code?

Tags: transition, movie, mpmovieplayer

My whole goal is to have a button on the main view, when you press this button a video plays and when the video is done playing you're now at the second view. The quick video is like a transition between the two VCs. My question is where should I put the 'play movie' code. Here are the scenarios I've tried and the unsatisfying outcomes:

The button in Main VC plays the movie and opens second VC - The movie plays but the second view controller doesn't open, just goes back to the main VC.

The button in Main VC plays the movie and the NSNotification for moviePlayBackDidFinish opens the second VC - same result as above.

The button in Main VC switches to second VC and movie code is in second VC's viewDidLoad (also viewWillLoad, same result) - VC switches but movie doesn't play

The button in Main VC switches to second VC and movie code is in second VC's viewDidAppear - second VC appears then movie plays continuously (not what I want).

What is the best way to set up the code to get the transition effect I'm looking for? Should I make a third View Controller in between the two just to play the movie? Here is the code I'm using to play the movie:

```
 //Sets up the movie file to play
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TransitionMovie" ofType:@"mov"]];
_moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                 initWithContentURL:url];
//Creates notification observer so it knows when the movie is done playing
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:_moviePlayer];
//Plays the movie
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:_moviePlayer];
```